# Created or Edited Files after Auto mount are missing after restart

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem, directory, automount

Yesterday I decided to auto mount a hard drive with "Disks". During the mount options change I was working with some files in VScode, after saving the changes, the files were readable and writable. The Directory and the files I was working with were visible. After a restart files were gone.The Directory is visible but without my program files and data. Others files that have not been used after the auto mount, are steal there.
I know that I should have made a git push or something like that. Unfortunately I have not.

Is there any chance that my files are still there but invisible? Is it possibly that I accidentally created an other filesystem that hangs from the same position and has stored the changes?

At first the hard drive was mounted manually to /media/Common.
The process took place in "Disks" at Mount options. There, the only thing I changed was the "Identify As" witch I select "LABEL=Common"

Also after the incident my hard drive is reporting read errors with increased Current Pending Sector Count

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:

```
|ID#| ATTRIBUTE_NAME|FLAG|VALUE|WORST|THRESH|TYPE|UPDATED|WHEN_FAILED|RAW_VALUE|
|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|
|1|Raw_Read_Error_Rate|0x002f|198|197|051|Pre-fail|Always|-|120|
|3|Spin_Up_Time|0x0027|180|179|021|Pre-fail|Always|-|3991|
|4| Start_Stop_Count|        0x0032|   100|   100|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       95|
|5 |Reallocated_Sector_Ct   |0x0033   |200   |200   |140    |Pre-fail  |Always       |-       |0|
|7| Seek_Error_Rate|         0x002e|   100|   200|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       0|
 | 9| Power_On_Hours|          0x0032|   098|   098|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       1508|
 |10| Spin_Retry_Count|        0x0032|   100|   253|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       0|
 |11| Calibration_Retry_Count| 0x0032|   100|   253|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       0|
 |12| Power_Cycle_Count|       0x0032|   100|   100|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       92|
|192| Power-Off_Retract_Count| 0x0032|   200|   200|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       7|
|193| Load_Cycle_Count|        0x0032|   200|   200|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       95|
|194| Temperature_Celsius|     0x0022|   115|   107|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       32|
|196| Reallocated_Event_Count| 0x0032|   200|   200|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       0|
|197| Current_Pending_Sector|  0x0032|   200|   200|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       12|
|198| Offline_Uncorrectable|   0x0030|   100|   253|   000|    Old_age|   Offline|      -|       0|
|199| UDMA_CRC_Error_Count|    0x0032|   200|   200|   000|    Old_age|   Always|       -|       0|
|200 |Multi_Zone_Error_Rate|   0x0008|   100|   253|   000|    Old_age|   Offline|      -|       0|
```

I don't know if the auto mount settings have any connections with the problem, but those were the latest changes of any kind on that hard drive.

Currently I'm using:
Ubuntu Mate 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.11.0-41-generic x86_64
MATE 1.24.0

Comment: sounds like you didn't mount the drive and you wrote them to the mountpoint(/media/Common)..... OR .......... you mounted the drive, wrote the files to the drive, rebooted, and the drive is not mounted now, and you are just looking at the mountpoint instead of the drive..... check both places

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion. I took this hard drive to a data recovery center. Unfortunate, it has many corrupted sectors in which the firmware of the drive is in.